# Sort each dictionary in a list of dictionaries, separately by its values - Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I am trying to make tags for clusters of survey responses using the words lists created by bags of words.

Each words list is a dictionary that is part of a row corresponding to the cluster it is in.  These attributes are part of a PANDAS data frame.  Other attributes will be added to the data frame later on, so I need to preserve the rows.

I want to sort each dictionary by the count of each of the words in it, in descending order. The words are the keys, the counts are the values.

This data frame consists of:

2 columns of data: df[['cluster#', 'dictionary']]

Cluster# = an integer

dictionary = {word0:count0, word1:count1, ..., wordx:countx}

For each cluster number, I want the corresponding dictionary to be ordered descending by count.  (Each dictionary has a unique number of elements, defined by the number of unique words in the cluster.  But that shouldn't matter)

How can I do this using Python?  I will be using the words lists as descriptive tags for the clusters.

Comment: Can you let us see the actual dictionary? What you have is quite confusing to understand.

Comment: Instead of actually sorting the dictionaries, would it be possible to just _access_ them in sorted order?  i.e. something like `for key in sorted(mydict.keys()):`

Comment: Ann, the dictionaries are defined clearly above.  Seeing what is in them won't help you understand the process any better than the definition would.  They vary by cluster number and they are very large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do :

```
# First define a function that reverse-sorts a dictionary by values
def sort_dict(d):
    return {k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

# Apply that function to the 'dictionary' column of your dataframe
df['dictionary'] = df['dictionary'].apply(sort_dict)
```

Comment: @AlexJarvis Great! Please consider marking the answer as accepted if you're happy with the solution.